# Manga where the MC is transported to another world with three friends, but is betrayed and pushed off the transportation circle by one of the friends

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

In the beginning, the main character (MC) and three of his friends are transported to a different world and the god gives them gifts and asks them to step inside the transportation circle. But one of the friends (a male) pushes him out of the circle, which makes his teleport to a different location. The god sees this all and gives the gift of the betrayer to the MC.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: If someone posts a correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like [Kamisama ni Kago 2-nin Bun Moraimashita](https://myanimelist.net/manga/132740/Kamisama_ni_Kago_2-nin_Bun_Moraimashita). The synopsis below matches your description on all counts.

> As he was being transferred to a different world with his classmates, Fubuki Amasaka was pushed out of the teleportation circle by his class bully, Yushin. When he woke up, he was alone and deep in a forest. However God, who had saw the entire thing and already warned them to stay in the circle, took Yushi's cheat skill away and gave it to Fubuki as punishment. Can Fubuki, who got two divine blessings, live in a different world safely?